# Rebuilding custom Index on Sitecore Azure WebApp doesn't work

Tags: azure, indexing, lucene, azure-search

I'm new to Azure deployments. We have installed Sitecore 8.2 webapp and deployed and everything works fine except that our custom indices have not been created. Pages that use indices crash.
Rebuilding indices through Sitecore completes right away and the folder under App_Data does not get created.
We're using Lucene. Are we missing something?

Comment: Are your indices configured for Lucene or Azure Search?

Comment: We're using the default Lucene configurations

Comment: In PaaS you either have to use Azure Search or Solr or Coveo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default installation of Sitecore on Azure PaaS is using Azure Search. Lucene indexing is not supported as it is a file based solution. In PaaS you either have to use Azure Search or Solr or Coveo.

**Make sure to update your custom index config file before publishing and rebuilding the index.**

If you are using Azure Search, please read the features and limitations: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/sitecore_azure_search_overview

Comment: Previous versions did support Lucene as long as there was only 1 instance of the web app - is this a change with 8.2?